# SQL Server: 1 random in join 2 tables

Tags: sql-server, join, random

I have `table1` and `table2`; I need a result set where for each row in table 1 there will be 1 (different for every row from 'table1') random value from 'table2'.

I've tried

```
select 
  t1.num, t2.char 
from
 table1 t1
join/apply (select char from table2 order by NewID()) t2
```

but it return the same random value from t2 for each row t1
(1,b; 2, b; 3, b; 4, b; 5, b)

I need different random row from 'table2' for each t1 row

also tried

```
select *
from 
  (select num, t2.char, row_number() over(partition by num order by newid()) rn from t1
   cross join t2
   ) tt
where rn = 1
```

it worked, but initially t1.count = 1000000 and t1.count = 14000. Cross join will take forever

Example:

- table #1: (1; 2; 3; 4; 5)
- table #2: (a; b; c)

Desired result set:

```
(1,c; 2,b; 3,a; 4,a; 5,b)
```

Not accepted:

```
(1,a; 2, a; 3, a; 4, a; 5, a)
(1,b; 2, b; 3, b; 4, b; 5, b)
(1,c; 2, c; 3, c; 4, c; 5, c)
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Is `(1,a; 2, a; 3, a; 4, a, 5, a)` an acceptable solution or are there, not mentioned, constraints to the random value from table 2 ?

Comment: No, it should be different values from table2

Comment: That why this is a bad question, I can pick randomly the first value multiple times.....  So, please, explain all the rules that apply.

Comment: LOL, selecting the 'c' 5 times is allowed..... 

Comment: If you remove the orderby, it's random as the order isn't guaranteed.

Comment: please reopen the question, need help with that

Comment: @Luuk Please reopen

Answer (score 0):

OK, apart from the fact that my solution CAN return 5 times the same result from table2, I will post it:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte as (
    select 1 as X, ROUND(RAND() * 2) as R
    union all
    select X+1, ROUND(RAND() * 2) as R FROM cte WHERE X<=5),
    table1 as (select 1 as a union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5),
    table2 as (select 'a' as b union select 'b' union select 'c')
select a,b
from (
select row_number() over (order by a,b) R, a,b, ROUND(RAND() * 2) RR
from table1
   cross join  table2
) z
inner join cte on cte.X=a and z.R%3=cte.R;
```

The dbfiddle is: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ef070fc3959853d98323cfccb5850eec

P.S. I am open to suggestions (from anyone) on how to avoid selecting 5 times the same value.

Comment: Thanks for the help, cross join will work, but when table1 has 1M rows and table2 - 14k, cross join throw Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException'. :(

Comment: I am still thinking about a way to avoid the cross join....   Are the numbers in table1 consecutive ? (Does it start at 1, and increment per record with 1, until 1M ?)